# Connection reset by peer: socket write error - using java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to code server - client to transfer file.

My problem is when I use file with small size. It's Ok, but when I use bigger size, it has:

> "Connection reset by peer: socket write error".

[image]

Comment: Please do not add code as image. Add it as text instead. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on how to add code to your question.

Comment: You haven't posted the peer code but it is clearly in error. As is this code. You can't assume that `read()` fills the buffer. That's why it returns a count.